# Dynamically create a multidimensional array in date order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to work out a way to create a multidimensional array from a previous array, and then sort it into date order.

Presently my array looks like this:

```
array(5) {

[0]=> string(161) "2013-09-18~Ready For Retina HD: Create Pixel-Perfect Assets For Multiple Scale Factors~ready-for-retina-hd-create-pixel-perfect-assets-for-multiple-scale-factors"
[1]=> string(93) " 2010-10-20~Taking A Closer Look At Tech Conferences~taking-a-closer-look-at-tech-conferences"
[2]=> string(71) " 2014-10-19~Wayfinding For The Mobile Web~wayfinding-for-the-mobile-web" [3]=> string(60) " 2014-05-15~Freebie: Icons Of Autumn~freebie-icons-of-autumn"
[4]=> string(1) " "

}
```

Each array element now needs to be further broken down by using the delimiter `~`, I had previously done this using a foreach loop however this created 3 different arrays of data, not one multidimensional array.

I obviously need to name each of the values, `$date`, `$title` and `$filename`.

How would you do this with a foreach loop so that it stores it in one multi-dimensional array? This is what I had previously

```
foreach ($masterpostlist as &$post){
    $post = explode('~',$post);
}
```

How would you then sort the date part of the array so that they order newest first?

Comment: why don't you use multidimensional arrays to store your result in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways you can do this, but I think the shortest (in terms of code to write) I can think of is to use `array_map` and `usort`.
First, let's establish what we have to do:

- Sanitize data: You have an empty string (`' '`) in your array, we need to get rid of that and some of your strings contain leading spaces, so we'll have to get rid of that, too
- Then, assign each chunk of data to the corresponding keys
- Compare all the dates and sort accordingly

First things first, let's sanitize the data:

```
//assume $a is your array:
$a = array_filter(//gets rid of empty keys
    array_map('trim', $a)//trim each element in $a
);
```

Next, let's create a 2D array, where each index contains an assoc array with the keys *date, title and filename*:

```
$x = array_map(
    function($value)
    {
        return array_combine(
            ['date', 'title', 'filename'],//the keys
            explode('~', $value)//the values
        );
    }, $a);
```

Then lastly, let's sort the lot:

```
usort($x, function($a, $b)
{
  $dateA = new DateTime($a['date']);//create a DateTime object from value
  $dateB = new DateTime($b['date']);
  if ($dateA == $dateB)//if both dates are the same
      return 0;//don't move
    return $dateA < $dateB ? 1 : -1;//descending order
});
```

## [live demo here](https://eval.in/207913)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this example:

```
$arr = array("2013-09-18~Ready For Retina HD: Create Pixel-Perfect Assets For Multiple Scale Factors~ready-for-retina-hd-create-pixel-perfect-assets-for-multiple-scale-factors", "2013-09-20~Ready For Retina HD: Create Pixel-Perfect Assets For Multiple Scale Factors~ready-for-retina-hd-create-pixel-perfect-assets-for-multiple-scale-factors", "2013-09-15~Ready For Retina HD: Create Pixel-Perfect Assets For Multiple Scale Factors~ready-for-retina-hd-create-pixel-perfect-assets-for-multiple-scale-factors");
$new = array();
foreach($arr as $v) {
    $ex = explode("~", $v);
    $new[] = array('date'=>$ex[0], 'title'=>$ex[1], 'detail'=>$ex[2]);
}

print_r($new);

// Newest Date First
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return  strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date']);
}
usort($new, 'sortByOrder');

print_r( $new );
```

Hope this is what you want; <kbd>[DEMO](http://codepad.org/mcx6Yb1e)</kbd>

Comment: In your demo, why does it output the array three times when they are all duplicates?

Comment: @Francesca I only copied `[0]=> string(161)` value and pasted three time with different date( Cause you want to sort the value by date ) that why ;)